# Python regex search ends with cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am using the `search` function in a regex expression in a while loop. 
But the program ends with `ValueError: cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern`.
If I use a pattern that is not compiled, it ends with: `ValueError: ASCII and UNICODE flags are incompatible`. I use Python 3.81. How to fix this?

(I was able to run the program successfully with `finditer`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re

text = 'This island is beautiful and is large'

pattern = re.compile(r'\bis\b')
# pattern = r'\bis\b'

idx = 0
# match = re.search(pattern, text, pos=idx)

while True:
# while (match := re.search(pattern, text, idx)):
    # pattern = re.compile(r'\bis\b')
    match = re.search(pattern, text, idx)
    if match == None:
        break
    print(match.group())
    idx += match.endpos
```

Comment: re.search only takes two parameters. def search(pattern, string, flags=0):. What are you trying to do with this code with idx?

Comment: @MarcusRenshaw repeatedly apply on the text; that is, find all the occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument of `re.search` defines the flags.

If you want to specify the position, use:

```
 Pattern.search(string[, pos[, endpos]])
```